# How do i increment a value of column with condition?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, on-duplicate-key

my table looks something like this

```
id effect1(int) effect2(int) effect3(int) 
1     0           1               5
2     1           0               0
```

i have a function, which return 1to3 int value representing effect1,effect2,effect3 and "id"

i am trying to increment value of each effect by 1  when my function's returning "id" matches the "id" from my dataset otherwise creates new row and increase value of effect

**for example**

if my function returns (1,3)
my table will become

```
id effect1(int) effect2(int) effect3(int) 
1     0           1               6
2     1           0               0
```

if my function returns (3,3)
my table will become

```
id effect1(int) effect2(int) effect3(int) 
1     0           1               6
2     1           0               0
3     0           0               1
```

i have tried the following code using python, but failed.
can someone please help me out here

```
i = (1,3) # the returning value from my function
if i[1] == 1:
    sql = "update test set effect1=effect1+1 WHERE id= ({})".format((str(i[0])))
    db.execute_query(myDb, sql)
elif i[1] == 2:
    sql = "update test set effect2=effect2+1 WHERE id= ({})".format((str(i[0])))
    val = (i[0],)
    db.execute_query(myDb, sql )
elif i[1] == 3:
    sql = "update test set effect3=effect3+1 WHERE id= ({})".format((str(i[0])))
    val = (i[0],)
    db.execute_query(myDb, sql )


def execute_query(connection, query):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        connection.commit()
        print("Query successful")
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your implementation, you did not check if the `id` already exists or not.

I updated your code with an SQL statement that performs insertion/update as you mentioned-

- in case the `id` exists then only the specific effect needs to be increased
- if `id` does not exist then a new row with that `id` needs to be added/inserted into the `test` table)

I also replaced the variable `i` (a list of two elements), with two variables named `id` and `effect_no` to improve the readability of the code. The `if` `else` statements are also not needed as the `effect_no` can be used/incorporated into the sql statement itself.

Following is the updated code:

```
id, effect_no = (1,3) # the returning value from your function
sql = f"""INSERT INTO test (id, effect1, effect2, effect3)
VALUES ({id}, 0, 0, 0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE effect{effect_no} = effect{effect_no} + 1"""
db.execute_query(myDb, sql)

def execute_query(connection, query):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        connection.commit()
        print("Query successful")
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")
```

Also, I found the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` SQL statement here https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/#using-insert--on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: but you are assigning the other values as zero. The other data will be lost if I do that.

Comment: please, could you possibly share which other values are being assigned as `0`? Currently, when there is no row in the table with a given `id`, a new row with that given `id` and `0` value for the effects is being assigned.

Comment: My apologies, your code was actually working. However, I had one issue here, which I have resolved. Since you assigned the other values a zero, each effect would have 1 fewer, as you started from 0. the changes i made is `idd, effect_no = (1, 3)  # the returning value from my function
    sql = f"""
    INSERT INTO testy (id, effect{effect_no}) VALUES ({id}, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE effect{effect_no} = effect{effect_no} + 1
    """`

Comment: `INSERT INTO test (id, effect1) VALUES (5, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE effect1 = effect1 + 1`

Comment: Great! Happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `id` is the primary key of the table or it is defined as unique, you can use MySql's [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) like this:

```
i = (1, 3)
sql = """
INSERT INTO test (id, effect1, effect2, effect3)
SELECT id, (n = 1), (n = 2), (n = 3) FROM (SELECT ? id, ? n) t
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE effect1 = effect1 + (n = 1), 
                        effect2 = effect2 + (n = 2), 
                        effect3 = effect3 + (n = 3);
"""
db.execute_query(myDb, sql, i)

def execute_query(connection, query, i):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(query, i)
        connection.commit()
        print("Query successful")
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=adc69df6b4c24f691bfe069d9bee17d9) of how this works in MySql.

Comment: thanks man, its working :D